# The 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered error

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I know that this must have been asked but I think I have tried all the suggestions written.

I am using:

- Win 7 x64
- Office 2010(32 bit).
- MSFT Access Database 2010(32 bit)
- MSFT Office Access Database engine 2007.

My project is **ANY CPU** but still getting this error.
Here is my connection string

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";
  Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";"
```

I have also checked my App Pool is currently set to **False** for 32 bit applications.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Try installing this (there are versions for 32 and 64 bit): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: App Pool should be set to **True** for 32 bit applications.  That is what was causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f11b2df9-fd0a-4528-987f-f95dfdccee0a/) might help you.

Comment: what is chr(34)? Can you please explain and do I need to define chr?

Comment: Sorry. chr(34) represents quotation marks. I was assuming you were storing the connection string in a string variable. Are you?

Comment: Yes I m.But I copied exactly you mentioned above and chr is undefined.

Comment: I think you meant (char)34?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just realized that you are using C#. The chr(34) is for use in VB. Did you check out that MSDN page I linked?

Comment: Yeah, none could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually spent my entire day to debug but couldn't get anything working.
So I started looking options and found this option "http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/" and it worked for me.